# How can i add values to a existing table column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where i have a column called student id and in that column i want to insert like SN + userid.But i know how to create a new column and do this but i want to add this to an existing column whenever a user is inserted.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Profile_Master]
Add [new] as ('SN'+CONVERT([varchar] (10),[UserId],(0)))
```

Comment: Quite a few ways to do this. What's the DBMS?

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you have now, how it's not working, and how you would like it to work?

Comment: I am using sql server...

Comment: update the student id to be equal to the student id + the SN

Comment: That depends on the DBMS (retag your question), check if yours supports TRIGGERs.

Comment: This is working but i already have a column with student id so i want to insert into that column

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you can use triggers to do this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Comment: OTOH, a VIEW might also do, if you don't need the column to be persistet.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is already compliant to your requirements: you are creating a computed column.

Thus, it will work for existing records and for new ones created in the future.

Comment: Yes i am creating a computed column but the thing is that is it possible to insert the data into the existing column?not a new column

Comment: If you really want to insert/update the data -> see my answer about triggers ;-)